# Сборка iOS приложения для тестирования

Tags: ios, юнит-тесты

Есть удаленная машина Mac Mini, на ней и ведется разработка.

Необходимо прислать билд приложения для установки на телефоне тестировщика в один клик, с помощью чего это можно сделать?
Ранее был сервис: buddybuild

Но его закрыли, есть ли альтернативные, желательно бесплатные.

Answer (score 0):

Apple предоставляет бесплатный сервис TestFlight при наличии подписки на Apple Developer Program или Enterprise. Если вы собираетесь распространять приложение через App Store или ad-hoc в пределах организации, вам всё равно понадобится одна из этих подписок, так что дополнительных затрат именно на TestFlight не нужно. В самом TestFlight можно распространять как приватную бету для тестировщиков (internal testing), так и публичное бета-тестирование на аудиторию до 2000 человек.

Если TestFlight вам не подходит, есть также сторонние сервисы – Fabric Beta, HockeyApp (Visual Studio App Center), DeployGate, Testfairy.